# Unable to reach code from bundle js from another script tag

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am trying to initiate Model3dLauncher instance.
But I got:
`Model3dLauncher is not defined`

```
// index.js
...
    <script type='text/javascript' src="./bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var G110_MODEL = new Model3dLauncher();

        G110_MODEL.init();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    watch: true,
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.m?js$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            keep_fnames: true,
          },
        }),
      ],
    },
};
```

In bundle.js, I could see that there is Model3dLauncher function, but I still couldn't create a new instance from the second script tag. Do you have any explanation for this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just make sure you have declared `Model3dLauncher` globally in the `bundle.js` i.e `window.Model3dLauncher`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I got it works by ```window.Model3dLauncher = Model3dLauncher``` in `Mode3dLauncher.js`
I'm pretty sure there is better practice than this, but your idea helped. thanks!

Comment: Yes, ofcouse there is way but then you will have to include the instantiation of the `Model3dLauncher` in the `bundle.js` code, which then will be bundled together and won't cause a problem